# How to get other people's question updates in global inbox?

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

When I see some good question I'd like to star it and pay attention to its updates (answers, edits, comments). So it's good to see new message from the inbox messages, but it seems that I can only check these questions under my Favorites tab which I forget to do sometimes.

So, is there any way to get other people's question updates in an inbox message? If not, I think I'd like to have this new feature.

Comment: Doesn't the "favourites" feature do exactly what you want?

Comment: No,I didn't receive any updates in my inbox message,is this has something related to my reputation??@Pëkka